# How to keep the comments in markdown

Tags: markdown

When I write markdown with some comments, when it turned into html, the comments is gone. I wonder if there is a way to keep the comments ?

For example, markdown file is

```
## Title
<!-- This is a title -->
```

which I want is when this file turned into a html, the second line still keeps.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which implementation of `markdown` are you using? Many implementations keep the comment in the HTML ouput.
Mine markdown (on Ubuntu) keeps the comments in the HTML output.

You can check other implementations, and to some tests here:
[babelmark.bobtfish.net/](http://babelmark.bobtfish.net)

Answer (score 0):

There are some Markdown processors that allow HTML comments; some are disabled due to security or other reasons.

GitHub and BitBucket README markdown disable HTML comments.

Look at this link:
https://gist.github.com/dupuy/1855764

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com . You can improve your answer by summarizing the essential points of the linked website for this problem.